# Counting a range of values IF they occur for a certain time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe set up to import from a csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_path',
                 parse_dates={'timestamp': ['Date','Time']},
                 index_col='timestamp',
                 usecols=['Date', 'Time', 'X'],)
```

So it ends up having a datetime as the index and an int64 object 'X' for the value.

My data looks like this with two columns:

```
              X
timestamp   
2015-08-25 16:52:10 95
2015-08-25 16:52:12 84
2015-08-25 16:52:14 86
2015-08-25 16:52:16 84
2015-08-25 16:52:18 85
2015-08-25 16:52:20 86
2015-08-25 16:52:22 84
2015-08-25 16:52:24 95
2015-08-25 16:52:28 95
2015-08-25 16:52:48 80
2015-08-25 16:52:50 85
2015-08-25 16:52:52 85
2015-08-25 16:52:54 84
2015-08-25 16:52:56 85
2015-08-25 16:52:58 86
2015-08-25 16:53:00 85
2015-08-25 16:53:02 85
2015-08-25 16:53:04 85
2015-08-25 16:53:06 86
2015-08-25 16:53:08 85
2015-08-25 16:53:10 85
```

The interval isn't always consistent, however. Sometimes I have data points that are more than two seconds apart (i.e. 16:52:28-16:52:48).

My desired values are X = [84, 86] but ONLY IF they occur for **at least 10 continuous seconds.**

So in my dataframe, I would want python to only return a count of 2 for 16:52:12-22 and 16:52:50-16:53:10.

How do I tell python to not count 16:52:50-16:53:10 as 2? I can code for a specific time interval, but how do I translate "at least Y continuous seconds" into python?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To clarify, my preferred output would be a count of how many times Event Y occurs within a sample set. Event Y occurs when X has a value for at least 10 consecutive seconds. So for example, if X is at 84-86 for at least 10 consecutive seconds, then I would want that to be a count of 1.

Comment: Could you please provide the desired output for this example? That would clarify the question a bit more.

Comment: thanks for the input, will do

Comment: Sorry, but there is one point that remains not clear for me. What do you mean by "at 84-86". It is simple if we condider that the value of X remains the same at least 10 consecutive seconds. But you want to check if it remains in an interval during 10 seconds ?

Comment: @RomainX yes, that's exactly it. I want to check if it remains in the range of 84-86 for at least 10 consecutive seconds

Comment: Define **10 continous seconds** in this case. Time is continuous no matter what; your samples of that time may not be.

Comment: In this case, 10 continuous seconds means 10 consecutive seconds.

Comment: `In this case, 10 continuous seconds means 10 consecutive seconds.` That is circular. Are you saying a period of at least 10 seconds where the sample rate is every 2 seconds without interruption?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of exactly what you want to do, but I give you an answer at least to help to clarify the expectations.

```
# Test data    
df = pd.DataFrame([('2015-08-25 16:52:10', 95),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:12', 84),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:14', 86),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:16', 84),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:18', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:20', 86),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:22', 84),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:24', 95),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:28', 95),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:48', 80),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:50', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:52', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:54', 84),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:56', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:52:58', 86),
  ('2015-08-25 16:53:00', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:53:02', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:53:04', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:53:06', 86),
  ('2015-08-25 16:53:08', 85),
  ('2015-08-25 16:53:10', 85)],
                 columns=['timestamp', 'x'])

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('timestamp')

# Define a period column to indicate the period when the values occur
new = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10s'),as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['x'])
df['period'] = new.index.get_level_values(0)
# Group by period and value and count the number of values to see the distinct values and how many time they occur by period
df = df.reset_index()
grouped = df.groupby(['period','x']).count()
print(grouped.head(10))

           timestamp
period x            
0      84          2
       85          1
       86          1
       95          1
1      84          1
       86          1
       95          2
3      80          1
4      84          1
       85          3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand that will help me evaluate what I'm getting. I added the original post to hopefully make my desired result clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example:

```
>>> df
             timestamp   x
0  2015-08-25 16:52:10  95
1  2015-08-25 16:52:12  84
2  2015-08-25 16:52:14  86
3  2015-08-25 16:52:16  84
4  2015-08-25 16:52:18  85
5  2015-08-25 16:52:20  86
6  2015-08-25 16:52:22  84
7  2015-08-25 16:52:24  95
8  2015-08-25 16:52:28  95
9  2015-08-25 16:52:48  80
10 2015-08-25 16:52:50  85
11 2015-08-25 16:52:52  85
12 2015-08-25 16:52:54  84
13 2015-08-25 16:52:56  85
14 2015-08-25 16:52:58  86
15 2015-08-25 16:53:00  85
16 2015-08-25 16:53:02  85
17 2015-08-25 16:53:04  85
18 2015-08-25 16:53:06  86
19 2015-08-25 16:53:08  85
20 2015-08-25 16:53:10  85
```

First, let's get a new column with the interval between two time stamps:

```
>>> tl=df['timestamp']
>>> df['interval']=[(tl[i+1]-tl[i]).total_seconds() for i, _ in enumerate(tl[:-1])]+[0]
>>> df
             timestamp   x  interval
0  2015-08-25 16:52:10  95         2
1  2015-08-25 16:52:12  84         2
2  2015-08-25 16:52:14  86         2
3  2015-08-25 16:52:16  84         2
4  2015-08-25 16:52:18  85         2
5  2015-08-25 16:52:20  86         2
6  2015-08-25 16:52:22  84         2
7  2015-08-25 16:52:24  95         4
8  2015-08-25 16:52:28  95        20
9  2015-08-25 16:52:48  80         2
10 2015-08-25 16:52:50  85         2
11 2015-08-25 16:52:52  85         2
12 2015-08-25 16:52:54  84         2
13 2015-08-25 16:52:56  85         2
14 2015-08-25 16:52:58  86         2
15 2015-08-25 16:53:00  85         2
16 2015-08-25 16:53:02  85         2
17 2015-08-25 16:53:04  85         2
18 2015-08-25 16:53:06  86         2
19 2015-08-25 16:53:08  85         2
20 2015-08-25 16:53:10  85         0
```

Now, use Python's groupby to get each interval span:

```
fmt='{} sec interval between {} and {} every {} seconds\n\tx={}, count={}\n'
for k, l in groupby(df.iterrows(), key=lambda row: row[1]['interval']):
    li=list(l)
    t2, t1=li[-1][1]['timestamp'], li[0][1]['timestamp']
    ti=(t2-t1).total_seconds()
    if ti>=10.0:
        data=[e[1]['x'] for e in li]
        print fmt.format(ti, t1, t2, k, data, Counter(data))
```

Prints:

```
12.0 sec interval between 2015-08-25 16:52:10 and 2015-08-25 16:52:22 every 2.0 seconds
    x=[95, 84, 86, 84, 85, 86, 84], count=Counter({84: 3, 86: 2, 85: 1, 95: 1})

20.0 sec interval between 2015-08-25 16:52:48 and 2015-08-25 16:53:08 every 2.0 seconds
    x=[80, 85, 85, 84, 85, 86, 85, 85, 85, 86, 85], count=Counter({85: 7, 86: 2, 80: 1, 84: 1})
```